# Selenium and Python: explicit wait for postback in select (wait for Javascript with Selenium)

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select various elements of a list, working with Python and Selenium. The `<select>`class comes with a `Postback`in Javascript like:

```
onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'dum1$dum2$dum3$ListBoxThingsToSelect\',\'\')', 0)"
```

When I try to select a value with Selenium, it only works for the first value and then the DOM changes and I am getting a `StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no longer attached to the DOM`error.

Thus I try to wait for the element to become available before clicking on it. I do this with the following code and the Expected Conditions (EC):

```
for row in vals_deselect:
    elem1 = WebDriverWait(browser, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((
            By.XPATH, "/html/body/form/div[11]/div[2]/fieldset/center/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/select[2]/option[" + str(row) + "]")))
    elem1.click()
```

This sometimes works for selecting more than 1 values but at some point either fails to click (the value is not clicked on) or results again in a `StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no longer attached to the DOM`error. Could anybody help? My theory is that the select element is located and clickable, but the page continues to load because there are more select elements to be loaded. Thus the DOM changes and when I try `elem1.click()`the DOM has changed.

How could I wait for the entire field to be loaded? 
What exactly does the `postback`do? 
I can unfortunately not post a link to the page, it is internal.

**EDIT1**

The `vals_deselect`is as list of indices of the indices I want to deselect. These indices do then get pasted into the `XPATH`in the loop to select the specific option from the select.
`vals_deselect = [1, 4, 5, 7, 9, 12]`

**EDIT2**
I have also tried the following:

```
print("jQuery.active: " + str(browser.execute_script("return jQuery.active")))
print("readyState: " + browser.execute_script("return document.readyState"))
WebDriverWait(browser, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
             "/html/body/form/div[11]/div[2]/fieldset/center/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/select[2]/option[" + str(row)+ "]"))).click()
```

It always shows that the `jquery.active`is 0 and the `readyState`is `complete`. I am getting desperate to solve this. I thought by checking the `readyState`and `jquery.active` I could check for the postback to be done. Any ideas by anyone?

The postback is looking exactly like on this page: http://aspalliance.com/articleViewer.aspx?aId=895&pId=-1
I need to wait for it to be done but how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `<select>` is refreshed after each time you choose an option you can use the `expected condition` [staleness_of](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.staleness_of). You should also use the [Select](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.select) to choose an option from `<select>` tag

```
for row in vals_deselect:
    selectElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[11]/div[2]/fieldset/center/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/select[2]")
    Select(selectElement).deselect_by_index(row)
    WebDriverWait(browser, 100).until(EC.staleness_of(selectElement))
```

As a side note, you should avoid using absolute path in your `xpath`. Try to find unique identifier for the element you are looking for as as close as possible in the html hierarchy.

**Update**

To answer the questions in the comments

*Could you please explain to me how this works? Does the fact that the element becomes stale mean that the post back has finished? Also, could you please explain what you meant by your comment about the `xpath`?*

`WebElement` become stale when it refreshed or changed, which means there is a new element even if it looks exactly the same (like in your case) or deleted. It can happen when the entire DOM is refreshed or changed or just a specific element. `EC.staleness_of` will wait until an element is no longer attached to the DOM or until the defined time is up.

There are several reasons not to use absolute `xpath`. Performance (much slower than relative `xpath` or methods like `find_element_by_id`), readability and fragility (imagine someone adds a `<div>` tag before the `<table>`. Absolute `xpath` will fail, relative will still work).

Comment: I tried your approach. But I get an error stating `AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'is_enabled'`Does this mean one cannot check for staleness_of for Select. Also, I should mention that I am trying to `deselect`by index, just in case it matters, initially all the values in the list are selected.

Comment: @rashid I've updated my answer. The use of `select` and `deselect` is the same, its not a problem.

Comment: This works well. Thank you a lot. Before I accept the answer, could you please be so kind to explain to me how this works? Does the fact that the element becomes stale mean that the postback has finished? Also, could you please explain what you meant by your comment about the `xpath`?

Comment: @rashid I added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. I accepted your answer and assigned the bounty to you. Haha my hard-earned reputation is gone :), I can only assign the bounty in 20 hours. I will do so.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

for row in vals_deselect:
        while not browser.execute_script("return document.readyState")== "complete":
            continue
        else:
            WebDriverWait(browser, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((
                By.XPATH, "/html/body/form/div[11]/div["
                          "2]/fieldset/center/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/select["
                          "2]/option[" + str(row) + "]")))
            ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(elem1).click().perform()
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. My `vals_deselect`is a list of strings, containing the text of the options I wish to deselect. There is no method `get_vals_deselect()`. Might this be the reason for the error? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you mean `vals_deselectis`  is a static list?

Comment: Yes, it is. Should it not be?

Comment: No its ok and it contains list of string?? can you give an example of that list?

Comment: Sorry, it is a list of indices, specifying which options to deselect. Please see **EDIT1** above.

Comment: Than why are you converting it into string? Indices must be integer and have you checked that after every click that xpath remains same?

Comment: Yes, the xpath remains the same. I am converting it to a string because by this I can paste it into the xpath, which is also a string. Is that wrong? I will be offline for 30 minutes, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: This works in terms of not creating a `StaleElementReferenceException:...`. However, the click is not sucessfully performed for all elements, some do not get deselected even though they are getting clicked on. When I put a `time.sleep(0.5)`in the loop it works fine. However, I want to avoid to wait. Could I somehow just wait until the `postback...`is done? Thanks so much for your help so far. Also, what does the `ActionChains`do?

Comment: ok Thanks. Any idea why I need the `time.sleep(0.5)`for the click to work?

Comment: Thanks for staying to help. I tried your solution but I get: `TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable`. What does this mean?

Comment: I am not sure whether I understood your answer correctly but I removed the `bool`part in front of the parenthesis. I still get the same error: `TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable`

Comment: I still get the same error. I tried with `WebDriverWait(browser, 100).until(lambda driver: browser.execute_script("return document.readyState") == "complete")`. It finishes the loop but somehow not all values get deselected, which is to say that some are being clicked on but do not get deselected.

Comment: Try updated answer. Ultimately it will wait until DOM is loaded completely. And if after even clicking its not getting selected, the problem must be something else not related to wait or DOM status.

Comment: Hello, I tried. It still does not work for all the values to deselect. Does the `readyState`also wait for changes made by JavaScript? I am going crazy about this haha. Is there any way to wait explicitly for the postback to be done?

Comment: :) ok thank you. I wanted to avoid time.sleep but I guess that is no longer an option. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Yeah, but by doing this you can get rid of stale element error.